# Include Relationship in Rails application with Grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape, grape-api

I'm returning a resource in API (I'm, using Grape) but I would like to return also the relationship objects (as included objects just as an ember application expects). How can I achieve that ? My serializer is as follow:

```
class JudgeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
    attributes :ID, :FIRST_NAME, :LAST_NAME, :FULL_NAME
end
```

My model:

```
class Judge < ApplicationRecord
    self.primary_key = 'id'
    self.table_name = 'judge'
    has_many :judgecourts, class_name: 'Judgecourt', primary_key: 'ID',foreign_key: 'JUDGE_ID'
end
```

I'm returning this resource this way:

```
desc 'Return a specific judge'
route_param :id do
  get do
    judge = Judge.find(params[:id])
    present judge
  end
end
```

It would be good to generate something like this:

```
data
:
{type: "judges", id: "1", attributes: {…}, relationships: {…}}
included
:
Array(1)
0
:
{type: "judgecourts", id: "1", attributes: {…}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like there are two topics in your question:

### 1. How to include a relationship in a ActiveModelSerializer

This can be done pretty easily by adjusting your active model serializer and adding the relation, so that ActiveModelSerializer knows that it must include the relation in the serialized objects:

```
class JudgeSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :ID, :FIRST_NAME, :LAST_NAME, :FULL_NAME

  has_many :judgecourts
end
```

This would automatically provide the `judgecourts` relation inside the serialized json. An example with the classic `Post/Comment` objects:

[image: Attributes adapter : a post with one comment]

### 2. Use specific format...

The format you specified looks a lot like JSON:API format. If that's what you're really wanting to achieve, then you might be better off using the JSON:API adapter built-in ActiveModelSerializer. For this, you need to tell AMS to use the proper adapter, maybe through an initializer file :

```
# ./initializers/active_model_serializer.rb
ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json_api
```

After this, your json should be formatted the way you seem to expect. I'm no expert in the json api specification, so there might be some more things to tweak. You'll be able to find more information about this adapter in [ActiveModelSerializers wiki page on adapters, section JSON API](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/general/adapters.md#json-api).

Here's what I get with my `Post/Comment` example:

### [image: json_api adapter : a post with one comment]

Note that there are other gems out there that were built to specifically address the JSON API specification, such as [jsonapi-rb](http://jsonapi-rb.org/) and Netflix [Fast JSON API](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi). They might be of interest for you.